# Video Indexer Displays blank dashboard

Tags: azure, azure-video-indexer

I want to highlight an issue that I am encountering with video indexer. On my machine, whenever I try to login to video indexer ( either microsoft or gmail account), it shows me blank dashboard like the one below:

[image: Blank Dashboard]

I have tried running it on other browsers and incognito as well (clearing browser cookies too). But nothing works on my machine. However, the same works fine when I log in through my other machine. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Hit F12 - Check the browser console for any reported errors

Comment: I see this error: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ezkydvuf4lb19eq/error.png?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you try incognito mode without any browser plugins/extensions.
Can you open the browser console and see if you are getting any errors or network issues?

Comment: Thanks for your response @Matan . I am getting this error in console: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ohns3h5d9tkhaap/error-2.png?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the GRAPH API is hitting a 401.

[image]

This is used to return the currently logged in user.

Since you are saying it is working in another machine fine.

The possibility I can think of is because of Conditional Access Policy(Location based mostly).

There could be some policies(for Security) that can be set at the tenant level which is making the Graph API to error out with 401.

The one machine is within the compliance (trusted network/vpn/domain joined etc.) where as the other one is not compliant. Hence the error.

Comment: can you suggest any fix for that ?

Comment: Can you pls confirm the difference between the device ? If yes, these are org level policies which may not be by passed without the Tenant Admin help. You ll have to request tenant admin for exception on your account